# Skype packages broken while trying to install from USC

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit here, it seems i have the same problem with this guy:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1074309

I ended up installing a deb from skype.com

But now when i try to open update manager:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```